# CSS styles not getting applied

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap project and I want to quickly change the `span`. So I have a `span` like that with my inline css:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <span style="color:#fff !important;padding-top:10px !important;font-size:26px !important;font-weight:bold !important; display: block">Title</span>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

But the thing is that style is not getting applied, however I can see the styles using dev tools:

[image]

Moreover then if I disable/enable any tickbox like that:

[image]

Then all styles gets applied.

Any ideas is what is going on and how to fix that?

Comment: What is your background color for the header?

Comment: @Ofisora it is black

Comment: https://codepen.io/Sahero/pen/prVEoa works fine here.

Answer (score 0):

when I tried it, everything is working except padding-top. To apply padding-top, use

```
display: block
```

or

```
display: inline-block
```

Edit:
Not sure if you know this already but span is an inline element which means, margin and padding will not take effect. Hence, you need to explicitly add display:block or inline-block